# Dual monitor setup disappears after switching off 2nd monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have a dual monitor setup which has been working fine in win10. Recently, I changed from using a hdmi cable to display port cable. Everything is working fine except one:

I realise that if I switch off my 2nd monitor, my dual monitor setup disappears and I'm left with a single monitor setup.  May I know why this is so? When I switch to using hdmi, there's no such problem.

Also, my 1st monitor is also using display port cable. But switching it off doesn't have this problem.

Is it because there's something special or wrong with my 2nd disply cable? Btw, it's a Ugreen 8K cable.

Thanks.